# identify links in pdf with php

Tags: php, linux, pdf

I want to create pictures out of a pdf. I know for linux there are free tools to do that. My problem is that I want to get links from a pdf file, identify them to use them later. So I would need to know which they are and also on what coordinates on that page, in order to be able to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert PDf to HTML eq "pdftohtml" and find href

Then with eq PHP dom get height of a href eq  $('a').offset().top;